# Nested If Logic and Bitwise Operators in a Javascript Function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to debug an issue with a Javascript function provided by a third party.

The function in it's entirety is here. 
Params:
b is an array of image data getImageData($image).Data
a is the width of the image
d is the height of the image

What I'm having trouble following is the 'If' statement in the second level 'For' loop. It's clear that the function is performing a mathmatical test on the imageData array passed as b, but the bitwise operators are throwing me for a loop.

Can anyone help me understand what the conditions are that evaluate the 'If' statment to true and which commands it calls when that 'If' is either true or false.

Thank you!

```js
funcName = function(b, a, d) {
  for (var e = [
      [-254, -126, -222, -94, -246, -118, -214, -86],
      [-62, -190, -30, -158, -54, -182, -22, -150],
      [-206, -78, -238, -110, -198, -70, -230, -102],
      [-14, -142, -46, -174, -6, -134, -38, -166],
      [-242, -114, -210, -82, -250, -122, -218, -90],
      [-50, -178, -18, -146, -58, -186, -26, -154],
      [-194, -66, -226, -98, -202, -74, -234, -106],
      [-2, -130, -34, -162, -10, -138, -42, -170]
    ], c = "", f = 0, g = 0; g < d; g++) {
    for (var h = 0, k = 128, l = 0; l < a; l++)
      if (((30 * b[f] + 59 * b[f + 1] + 11 * b[f + 2]) * b[f + 3] + 12800) / 25500 - b[f + 3] < e[g &
          7][l & 7] && (h |= k), f += 4, 0 == (k >>= 1)) c += String.fromCharCode(h), h = 0, k = 128;
    128 != k && (c += String.fromCharCode(h))
  }
  b = c;
  c = "";
  a = b.length;
  b += "\x00\x00";
  for (g = 0; g < a; g += 3) d = b.charCodeAt(g) << 16 | b.charCodeAt(g + 1) << 8 | b.charCodeAt(g + 2), c += "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/".charAt(d >> 18 & 63) + "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/".charAt(d >> 12 & 63) + "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/".charAt(d >> 6 & 63) + "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/".charAt(d &
    63);
  switch (a % 3) {
    case 1:
      return c.slice(0, -2) + "==";
    case 2:
      return c.slice(0, -1) + "="
  }
  return c
};
```

Comment: Hmm, that looks like the base64 alphabet. Is this just base64?

Comment: That's an awesome example of why it's better to not use assignments and a comma operator in the `if` statement

Comment: @NickODell That was my first thought, but if I encode the image as base64 it comes out with an entirely different string. It's a proprietary string format.

Comment: @zerkms I agree, it makes it ridiculously unreadable.